# How to pass a list from view to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have to pass a list of group from view to controller action. List of group is in Viewbag.Group. I have tried sending through url.action but its not working and also I am not sure whether we can send like this or not. Here is my code:

```
 @foreach (var x in ViewBag.Group)
        {           
            var active = Request.QueryString[x] == x ? "list-group-item active" : "list-group-item";
            <a class="@active" href=@Url.Action(x, "Search", new { searchText = ViewBag.searchText,grp=ViewBag.Group})>@x</a>
        }
```

Comment: Do you bind model to view?

Comment: No, I am just recieving that viewbag.Group from another action.

Comment: The `ViewBag` is for *one-way communication to the View* (hence the name *View* Bag). Can you provide more details about how you make the group in the first place, as that may affect the solution (passing a single id back vs. passing everything back in hidden fields)?